# Getting exception for getting instance of Worksheetpart using OpenXML

Tags: c#, excel, .net-3.5, openxml, openxml-sdk

We are using openXml to generate spreadsheet,and I need to get worksheetpart to work on the worksheet .
Below is the class we are using to generate the SpreadSheetDocument instance.

```
  public class Excelsheet
  {
    private readonly SpreadsheetDocument _spreadsheet;
    private readonly WorkbookPart _workbookPart;
    private readonly MemoryStream _memoryStream;
    private readonly Sheets _sheets;
    public WorksheetPart? _worksheetPart = null;
    public Excelsheet()
    {
        _memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        _spreadsheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(_memoryStream, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
        _workbookPart = _spreadsheet.AddWorkbookPart();
       _workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
        _sheets = _workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());
    }
    
    internal Spreadsheet OpenSheet(string name, string prefix,string suffixSheetno ="")
    {
        string fullName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix) ? name : prefix + name;
         fullName += suffixSheetno;
        _currentSheetName = fullName ;
        _worksheetPart = _workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        var sheet = new Sheet() { Id = _workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(_worksheetPart), SheetId = GetNewSheetId(), Name = fullName };
        _sheets.Append(sheet);
        DataWriter = OpenXmlWriter.Create(_worksheetPart);
        DataWriter.WriteStartElement(new Worksheet());
        _sheetOpen = true;
        _rowNumber = 0;
        return this;
    }

}
```

We are creating SpreadSheetDocument instance and working on it. We have a situation where we need more control on worksheetpart to modify values of cells.
I was trying to get worksheetpart from Spreadsheet document,but it is giving an exception for worksheet property

```
    WorksheetPart.worksheet is giving "System.Io. exception".
```

Here is the code to export to excel

```
public byte[] Export()
    {
        Excelsheet excelsheet = new();
        string namePrefix = string.Empty;
        excelsheet
                   .OpenSheet("TestAbc", namePrefix)
                   .OpenData();


        var worksheetPart=GetWorksheetPartByName(excelsheet,"TestAbc");



        spreadsheet            
           .CloseData()
           .CloseSheet();

        return spreadsheet.Render();
    }
    
    private WorksheetPart GetWorksheetPartByName(SpreadsheetDocument document, string sheetName)
    {
        IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets =
           document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().
           Elements<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == sheetName);

        if (sheets?.Count() == 0)
        {
            // The specified worksheet does not exist.

            return null;
        }

        string relationshipId = sheets?.First().Id.Value;

        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)document.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);

        return worksheetPart;
    }
```

Please let me know how to retrieve this sheet property

Comment: Is the excel file open or being consumed by another application?

Comment: Its open only.direct download  only

Comment: Is the error reproducible after restarting your machine and running the program only? Ca you share the full error stack with inner exceptions as well.